# How can I save a domain url in a single file and reuse it in different components?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, fetch-api

So, I have a domain url which I use it with different paths to make different requests to the api. so for example "api.example-url.com", I use it with different paths like "api.example-url.com/path1" and "api.example-url.com/path2", so I want to save the domain url in a single file and then import it in different components so I can use it with different paths and whenever the domain changes I can simply change the domain in that file. is that possible in reactjs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are different ways to do this one is to configure with

> webpack

Like this

```
    plugins: [
     new webpack.DefinePlugin({
     BASE_URL: (typeof process.env.BASE_URL !== 'undefined') ? 
      process.env.BASE_URL : 'http://localhost:3000'
     })
    ],
```

You can define this in your webpack config. so you can use anywhere in code.

Other is to define a constant and import this constant to use anywhere in the code.

```
export const BASE_URL = "http://example.com"
```

Comment: But I have a question is there a way better than the other? or just both get the job done?

Comment: Both are fine it's your priority if you want to user ENV variable or just want to use a constant both are recommended and fine

Comment: @Junaidaziz Please guide me that which one is a better solution?

Comment: Well, it depends upon you. But for me, I personally recommend using web pack settings.

Answer (score 4):

Use environment variables for that. You can get access to `process.env` by using the `webpack` plugin `DefinePlugin` or `EnvironmentPlugin`. Here is the documentation (https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/).

Let's say your environment variable name is `'ROOT_URL'` then you can create your url like below

`url = '${process.env.ROOT_URL}/YOUR_PATH'`

> UPDATE

In case you are using `create-react-app`. You can set your env variable name starting with `REACT_APP_[YOUR_VARIABLE]`. In your case, the variable name will be `REACT_APP_ROOT_URL` and the `url` will also get changed accordingly.

Comment: sorry I'm still a beginner with react and I'm using create-react-app, how can I achieve that?

Comment: Updated the answer. here is the more info about env variables in `create-react-app` https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables